# Camera services/processes

Tags: android, performance, android-camera

I'm profiling an app in android which makes use of the camera. I'm seeing a *high* CPU usage of two processes **/system/bin/cameraserver** and  **mm-qcamera-daemon** I would like to know what are they used for and if both of them are required by the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cameraserver is the Android service for the camera

mm-qcamera-daemon is a proprietary thing from Qualcomm, according to https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg26901.html it is polling the driver (which can explain high CPU load)

If your device is using Qualcomm SoC, you need both